# Based on the circumstances, should I continue to maintain contact with colleagues of a former place of employment?

Tags: communication, company-culture

I did some contract work for a distributed team that looked and felt like it was one of those organizations I have dreamed could and should exist where engineers come together for certain tasks depending on the contract (flat organization), but the reality seems to be something else (hierarchy).

While it seems like many contractors like myself have been hired for contracts here and there, they have a core team and it seems thats all that matters.

Supposedly, a company culture is supposed to be built around Slack channels, but doesn't happen. Heck I was more involved in the Slack channel than the core team that is currently still getting paid.

I keep in touch, I wish everyone well for the holidays, but I am feeling like a third wheel. The owner responds when I say hello, but I feel like he does it to just be professional.

Should I continue to bother keeping in touch?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I mentioned the third wheel part. Communication is a two way street. So my question I guess is within that context, is it pointless or do I continue to keep line of communication open?

Comment: @Daniel: none of this makes sense. You aren’t employed by them anymore. There’s no obligation and of course you feel like third wheel because you ARE. I’d feel weird responding to you on a Company albeit Conmunity Slack channel too if you weren’t employed anymore. It makes you seem desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to keep in touch with friends or people you got on well with, why not.

Slack however is not the best channel for that.

Companies tend use it for team communication or private chats during work.

Private conversations to stay in touch are best made over email, facebook, phone or in person.

- If you'd like to keep in touch with the boss for prospective future employment I suggest the same but instead of facebook something like linkedin is better.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't your problem, but companies that allow non-employees or non-contract employees to be in their 'official' slack and other communication channels are asking for trouble.

Do not be surprised if you get kicked, they really should have done this already.

IMO https://linkedin.com is the ideal place to develop and maintain these types of networking relationships, and you can still communicate directly in there as well.

There may be other third party places you can maintain connections that may be appropriate for your industry or country as well.  There may even be a community slack channel, but I would leave the 'company' one.

Comment: Bill, they had a work Slack channel that I am already off of, but the owner wanted to have a company culture/social Slack channel for non-contract employees and core employees, was my understanding, I mean the owner shared the link with me and he knew my contract was ending and we are are supposedly still seen as part of the company. Kind of like a lounge.

Comment: @Daniel: what’s the point? You are no longer employed by them and are no longer a part of the company. It’s time to move on.

Comment: @Daniel , click "Leave".

Comment: @Fattie, you commented twice, why not turn it into an answer? I ask because I saw another answer you once gave saying that the best way to get to know an employee is to do a paid trial, which I totally agree with so I think you and I are on the same page with certain workplace issues.

Comment: So think about this scenario.  The boss posts some 'materially important' information on this channel that indicates something good/bad is going to happen to company.  Now maybe this company is publicly traded, maybe not.  But lets say that now competitors are using this information to get sales away.  Now the boss is going to be looking for someone to blame who spilled the beans.   Do you want to be on that list?